# Error in approximating e via a finite sum

Tags: approximation, euler-mascheroni-constant

I need some help with a homework problem.

I have to find an upper bound for the error in approximating $e$ by the series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$$

I thought about using Taylor's theorem with the remainder term, but I didn't get very far with that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please reformat your expression

Comment: Your idea with Taylor's theorem will work. Have you tried looking at the error term in Taylor's theorem about 0 for $e^x$? (Hint: $e^x$ is increasing and in Lagrange form for the remainder your unknown constant is between $0$ and $x$)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid Taylor's theorem with some stingy estimations. Let $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!}$. Then
\begin{align*}
0 < e - s_n &= \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \cdots \\
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1 + \frac{1}{(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} +\cdots \right) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1 + \frac{1}{(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} +\cdots \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n} \\
&= \frac{1}{n!n},
\end{align*}
where the equality in line 4 comes from geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

For an upper bound,$$0<e-\sum_{k=0}^n k!^{-1}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} k!^{-1}=(n+1)!^{-1}  \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}[ (n+1)! k!^{-1}]=$$    $$(n+1)!^{-1}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}     (n+1)!(n+1+j)!^{-1}<(n+1)!^{-1} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^{-j}=$$ $$(n+1)!^{-1}((n+1)/n)=(n+1)!^{-1}(1+1/n).$$ A lower bound is $(n+1)!^{-1}$.